# Exceptions from Buildbots PeriodicScheduler intervals?

Tags: python, continuous-integration, build-automation, buildbot, nightly-build

Buildbots Periodic scheduler triggers builds at fixed intervals (e.g. every 30 minutes). But there are certain times (e.g. at night, during the weekend or while regular maintenance is performed) where I'd like it to relax.

Is there a way to have a more fine-grained description for the Periodic scheduler? Or should I rather use the Nightly scheduler and explicitly list all build trigger times I need for the whole week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Nightly`, then you can specify that the scheduler only trigger if there are interesting changes to build. Presumably, you won't have commits during that period either, so it will not trigger builds then.

Comment: Yes, but sadly the revision control system does not offer commit hooks of any kind. So the only to know if there are changes is to actually do a checkout...

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this would of course be to write a piece of python code that generates the build times for up the nightly scheduler according to some rules.